# Implementing genetic algorithm in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, algorithm

I want to implement genetic algorithm to find optimum location for placement problem with ArcGIS.

Can any body explain it (step by step ) or any resources about that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about genetic algorithms, but if you are using ArcGIS for optimal location, you will likely want to use the [Spatial Analyst extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Spatial_Analyst_toolbox/009z00000003000000/).  Possibly using a [weighted overlay](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Weighted_Overlay/009z000000rq000000/) or a [fuzzy overlay](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000rp000000.htm).

Here are some resources on [Optimization Methods](http://www.spatial.redlands.edu/sds/ontology/?n=SDSSMethodsAndTechniques%3aOptimizationMethod) and [Multi Criteria Analysis](http://www.spatial.redlands.edu/sds/ontology/?n=SDSSMethodsAndTechniques%3aMulticriteriaDecisionAnalysis) which may assist you.